# how to continue using the 32-bit API for C Matrix API on 64bit MCR

Tags: matlab, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, matlab-compiler

https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/upgrading-mex-files-to-use-64-bit-api.html

the article above mentions the following for MEX files.

***"You can continue to use the 32-bit API by calling the mex command with the -compatibleArrayDims option"***

We are calling the API functions via JNA. In other words, we are invoking functions exposed from libraries such as libmat and libmx. Is there a compatibleArrayDims option that we can use? Because it looks like this option is meant for MEX files only and we are not using MEX files

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/99144 the signature of the implementation of the functions has changed completely.

Now, it seems the main thing is how `mwIndex` and `mwSize` are defined.
I'd guess that the `-compatibleArrayDims` controls some `#define` which sets the type of `mwIndex` and `mwSize`.

I'd also assume there is a system variable which handles that for the DLL's.
So the best way to get it is to write a question for the technical team of MATLAB.